# Selecting the date from calendar

Tags: selenium, automation, datepicker, webautomation

how to select date from calendar?

There is calendar in a website. The way to select date is to click on any date and drag the mouse pointer to the desired date and then release mouse click.

Tried with ActionClass  but no success?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Share the details. Error , DOM of your calendar and the code snippet you have tried with.

Comment: @Test
public void selectDate() throws InterruptedException {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\A740493\\webautomation\\webauto\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
  
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
  
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
  driver.get("https://automationintesting.online/#/");
  Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='next']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='next']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='next']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='next']")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='closeModal']")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()= 'Book this room']")).click();
     System.out.println("clicked on button");

Comment: Thread.sleep(5);
  
   WebElement calendar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rbc-month-row'][4]"));
   
   Actions act = new Actions(driver);
   act.dragAndDropBy(calendar,628,1242).release().build().perform();
   calendar.click();

Comment: Above is the entire code i have created. The code contains the app URL: https://automationintesting.online/#/ I am not getting any error. Test case passes successfully. But its a false pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `act.dragAndDropBy(calendar,628,1242).release().build().perform();`

to

`act.dragAndDropBy(startDateWebElement,0,100).release().build().perform();`

It will select the rows on the calendar. You can try to work with below approaches as well by passing startDate and endDate locators:

```
WebElement startDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='16']/parent::div"));
WebElement endDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='22']/parent::div"));  

action.clickAndHold(startDate).moveToElement(endDate).click().release().build().perform();
action.dragAndDrop(startDate, endDate).build().perform();
action.clickAndHold(startDate).release(endDate).build().perform();
```